# What is the purpose of implication in this scenario?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Consider the case:

**Let:**

- S(x) = “x is a student”
- F(x) = “x is a faculty member”
- A(x, y) = “x has asked y a question”
- Dx and Dy = Consists of all people associated with your school.

*Use quantifiers to express this statement:*

---

### Some student has never been asked a question by a faculty member.

**Attempted Solution:**

*Exist* x, *All* y ( S(x) AND F(y) AND (NOT A(y, x)) )

**Book Solution:**

*Exist* x ( S(x) AND *All* y ( F(y) -> NOT A(y, x) ) )

***What is the point of using implication here? Would my answer also be correct?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make it slightly simpler.  Fix an $x$ and assume that $x$ is a student.  We want to say that $x$ has never been asked a question by a faculty member.  The relevant part of what you wrote is $\forall y\, (F(y) \mathbin{\And} \neg A(y,x))$.  However, this does not express the desired property of $x$.  The problem is that it asserts that *everyone* is a faculty member (even the janitors!)

To express "for all faculty members $y$,..." you should instead write "for all $y$, if $y$ is a faculty member, then...."  Admittedly, this is awkward English because first it asks us to consider *all* $y$ in the domain of discourse (even the janitors,) and then it becomes clear that we only care about faculty members $y$; that is, we only care about $y$ ***if*** $y$ is a faculty member.  This is where the *if* comes in.

So to express "$x$ has never been asked a question by a faculty member" we would write

(1) $\forall y\,(F(y) \implies \neg A(y,x))$.

This formula (1) translates to the awkward but correct English phrase "for all $y$, if $y$ is a faculty member, then $y$ has not asked $x$ a question."
Slightly less formally, and abusing notation by using $F$ for the set of faculty members rather than for the predicate "is a faculty member," we could write

(2) $\forall y \in F\; \neg A(y,x)$.

This formula (2) translates to the less awkward English phrase "for every faculty member $y$, $y$ has not asked $x$ a question."  However, in formal logic (2) is just defined to be an abbreviation for (1), so at its root the implication is still there.

Comment: Your explanation is awesome! But, what I am confused about now is that since you made a implication, there exists a scenario of F -> F = T. This in the context of the question doesn't make sense to me. Why would it be true? Or how would true make sense in this statement?

Comment: @mk1 If I understand you correctly, such a case arises when $y$ is not a faculty member, and $y$ has asked $x$ a question.  Then I refer you to  my answer to your earlier question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512751/what-is-the-purpose-of-implication-in-discrete-mathematics.  I think the reason it is confusing is that it is tempting to interpret the implication as "if $y$ _were_ a faculty member, then $y$ _would_ not have asked $x$ a question," and this would seems strange.  This would be the "counterfactual conditional" whereas mathematical logic uses the  "material conditional."

Comment: @mk1 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#Connective

Comment: What I am confused is. If F(y) is not true and A(y,x) is true such that the right side of the implication is false, then how can the statement be true. As in what does the statement being true actually mean now since its not dealing with faculty members anymore. Honestly, which I could chat this out with someone. I am really confused on this concept.

Comment: That's just how the (material) conditional is defined to work.  It is much more convenient that way, even though it doesn't always correspond to how "if" is used in natural language.  (And I'm afraid I don't like chatting in real time; perhaps there are other logicians in the chat room.)

Comment: That is understandable chatting with someone you don't really know is kinda weird. But, anyways, if you are dealing with a smaller portion of a bigger domain of discourse it is safe to say that you need to use implication?

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I think I understand now, but Ill crank out a few more problems and see how it goes. I might comment something here if I have any extra questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted solution is wrong on one point, and equivalent on the other.

The placement of the "All y" part is arbitrary between the two options - as $S(x)$ does not depend on $y$, it can be placed on either side of it (for lack of a better explanation).

For the implication, your implication is inaccurate - it implies that $F(y)$ for all $y$, as it can only be true if ALL of the conditions are true, since you used "and" for all of them.

On the other hand, here's how you'd write the book's answer without explicitly using implication:

$$\exists x \text{ s.t. } (S(x) \land \forall y, (\lnot F(y) \lor \lnot A(y,x)))$$

The english version of this is "There is a person who is a student and who, if you look at all other people, they are either not faculty or have not asked the student a question".

Comment: Can you please give the English version on my attempted solution?

Comment: It's a little hard to put in english because of the placement of the "all y" part, so I'll move it to the obvious place.

Comment: "There is a person who is a student and who, if you look at all other people, they are faculty and have never asked the student a question."

Comment: As you can see, it says that all other people are faculty (actually, my conversion to english is slightly inaccurate, both in my answer and in the previous comment - in both cases, the "all other people" should technically be "all people", including the student, but it reads strangely if you do that).